# only objectid is visible in mongodb as output

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I want to save data in mongodb, so i made an open schema. after post request it is getting uploaded in my database. but only objectid is shown in the database. I'm new to mongodb and even node, so i cannot pinpoint where my mistake is..

```js
// <---------server.js  ------->

const http = require('http')
const express = require ('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
// const router = require('./routes/hello')

const app = express();

// app.use(router)

app.use('/api', require('./routes/hello'))
 app.use('/api2', require('./routes/data'))


const MONG0_URL =  'mongodb+srv://aftrn:0WAXV8Bxjlf0fhMz@aftrn.3t9dptr.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority';


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000 ;

const server = http.createServer(app)


mongoose.connection.on('open', ()=>{
    console.log("Mongoose is ready !!")
})
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err)=>{
    console.log(err)
})






 function startServer(){
     mongoose.connect(MONG0_URL , {
        useNewUrlParser : true,
        useUnifiedTopology : true ,
    })
    server.listen(PORT,()=>{
        console.log('listening to port')
    })
}

startServer();
```

```js
// <-------------data.js-------------->

var Router = require('router')
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var express  = require('express')

var router = Router()


//schema 

const sch = 
   {
      name : String,
      email : String
     }


const monmodel = mongoose.model("aftrn col", sch) 
router.post('/obj2', async function(req,res){
 console.log("inside post fn")
   const data = new monmodel({
     name : req.body,
     email : req.body,
   })
  

const val = await data.save();  //saves data in collection
res.json(val);
console.log("data is stored")
 })

module.exports = router ;
```

my input to postman >

```js
{
    "name" : "bobby again ",
    "email" : " bobbyagain@lfc"
}
```

what I'm getting as output >

```js
{
    "_id": "632464434727474bed2a831f",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Thank you really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

For post you need bodyparser

`app.use(express.json())`

Change this

```
const data = new monmodel({
     name : req.body,
     email : req.body,
   })
```

to

```
const data = new monmodel({
     name : req.body.name,
     email : req.body.email,
   })
```

In Server.js

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(express.json());  // <----- here add post middleware
....
....
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: No its not working, getting this error -->  name : req.body.name,
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Comment: check your ```console.log(req.body)```

Comment: Its undefined  !!

Comment: i think change your collection name ```"aftrn col"``` to ```"aftrn_col"```

Comment: manually check ```name:"testName"``` is update are not

Comment: That didnt help, everything is same

Comment: @Ochaoash i updated answer kindly check it.

Comment: Thanks @dazil , but can u edit it with the code, I use used bodyparser in a line and it messed up it. also should i use name : req.body.name after using the body parser. this is what i had used (data.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

Comment: my suggested edit queue is full , you can add after app declaration.

Comment: ```express.urlencoded()``` for GET Requests or DELETE Requests. For POST you shoud use ```app.use(express.json())```

Comment: i used app.use(express.json) in app.js before starting server, no change in result. did i do anything wrong here

Comment: check my ans @Ochaoash

Comment: great, we have progress, even though column validation failed, the data got printed in console ///{
      stringValue: `"{ name: 'vandijk', email: ' vandijk@lfc' }"`,
      messageFormat: undefined,
      kind: 'string',
      value: { name: 'vandijk', email: ' vandijk@lfc' },
      path: 'email',
      reason: null,
      valueType: 'Object'
    }
  },
  _message: 'aftrn_col validation failed'
}

Comment: if you got ```{
 "stringValue": {
  "name": "vandijk",
  "email": "vandijk@lfc"
 }
}``` then use ```req.body.stringValue.name```

Comment: used {
      name : req.body.String,
      email : req.body.String,
    }) and its not returning the error,(it was on req.body.string.name) But the main problem of database is not changed, its returning object id only. But no error in the console. { name: 'vandijk', email: ' vandijk@lfc' }
data is stored.

Answer (score 0):

you are not creating schema. you need to write
`const schema=new mongoose.Schema({ name : String, email : String})`

Comment: I did what you have told, but getting the same result as mine, still only object ids as output